# The integral surface of the PDE $(x-y)u_x + (y-x-u)u_y = u$ passing through $u = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I can easily obtain

$\phi(x,y,u) = x+y+u =c_1$

and

$\psi(x,y,u) = \frac{y-x-u}{u^2} = c_2$

[see solution here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317488/x-y-u-x-y-x-u-u-y-u-and-ux-0-1).

but the difficult part is using $u = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ to the values of $\phi$ and $\phi$ to obtain the integral surface please help

Answer (score 1):

What would you say about the characteristic method? System of characteristic equations:

$$ \begin{cases} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{dt}}=x-y \\ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{dt}}=y-x-u \\\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{dt}}=u\end{cases} $$

and the initial conditions: $x(0)=\cos s, y(0)=\sin s, u(0)=1$. It can be solved in variables $x=x(t,s),y=(t,s),u=u(t,s)$. [Wolfram did it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dx%2Fdt%3Dx-y%3B%20dy%2Fdt%3Dy-x-u%3B%20du%2Fdt%3Du%3B%20x%280%29%3Dcos%20s%3B%20y%280%29%3Dsin%20s%3B%20u%280%29%3D1). The solution is a paramertized surface $\Sigma :\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$. And more specifically $$(t,s)\mapsto (x,y,u)$$
where:

$$x(t,s)=\frac{1}{2} \left(-e^{2 t} \sin (s)+e^{2 t} \cos (s)+\sin (s)+\cos (s)-2 e^t+e^{2 t}+1\right)$$

$$y(t,s)=\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{2 t} \sin (s)-e^{2 t} \cos (s)+\sin (s)+\cos (s)-e^{2 t}+1\right)$$

$$u(t,s)=e^t$$

The chart with the initial conditions looks something like this:

[image]